# Drawing edges while graph is being laid out in sigma.js

Tags: javascript, graph, sigma.js

The default behaviour in sigma is that while the graph is being laid out (i.e. the generator runs), edges are not drawn. Only after the layout finishes the edges are added, see [here](http://sigmajs.org/examples/random_clusters.html) for an example of what I mean.

Is there any way to draw the edges while the graph is laid out and not just at the end? I've seen suggestions that `sigInst.draw(2,2,2);` should force the edges to be drawn synchronously, but this code doesn't change anything regardless of where I put it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set batchEdgesDrawing to false to achieve this.  You will take a rendering hit, of course, but if your goal is watch as the graph is laid out including the edges, slower rendering may be just what you want :)

For example:

```
var settings = {
    batchEdgesDrawing: false,
};


var sigInst = new sigma({
  container: 'sigmadiv',
  settings: settings,
});
```